# Nginx double slash

Tags: regex, nginx

```
(?i)^/(dima|oleg)/([-a-z0-9]+)[.]+([-a-z0-9]+)[.]+(by|kz|ru)(((?<!/)/[-a-z0-9._\~\%\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\:\@]*)*)(\.php)((\?)(.*)?)?$
```

This regexp I use for rewriting urls. It suppresses urls with double slashes. You could test it on regex101.com. Works fine. BUT when I provide url with double slash to my NGINX server in access.log I could see just provided url as it is with double slashes and I get requested resource(for example .js file). But I expect something like 404 error because of double slash in url. The question is: why does this happen?

Comment: Web servers have an automatism build in to “ignore” such double slashes (Apache reacts the same way).

Comment: Yes, nginx has an option merge_slashes

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has an option merge_slashes on|off. This option is selfdescripted.